# unDeploy Apex Class using ANT

Tags: apex, deployment, ant

When I run the unDeploy code to remove an apex class in the environment the apex test start running.

Is that correct? Are they re-calculating to see if they linked and wont cause issues in the environment?

I cannot find anything in the documentation...

Comment: What test run level is your Ant build target specifying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running tests is a part of [almost any deployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm) to production, even the so-called "undeployment" (which is really just a destructive deployment). The system first validates that the items to be deleted have no external metadata dependent on them (e.g. if you try to delete a class referenced by a trigger, it will fail unless you're also deleting the trigger). This step occurs before the unit tests are run.

After the initial check to make sure that the deletion won't cause metadata problems, then unit tests are run to make sure it won't harm any business processes that may be implemented. Only after the validation of both metadata and unit tests have finished will the components be deleted.